# No text wrapping in HTML table on SharePoint

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, word-wrap, col

I have a table on SharePoint that I have constrained to a certain size. For this I have used table-layout:fixed; in my CSS. I then have  tags in my html to size my columns as I would like.

The problem is that when I use the  tags the white-space: nowrap; in my CSS seems to be ignored. I even tried putting in the white-space attribute straight into my  but to no avail.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    #box-table-a
    {
 font-family:arial;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 font-size:8pt;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:silver;
 border-width:1px;
 width:844;
 table-layout:fixed;
    }
    #box-table-a th
    {
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:300;
 padding:2,2,2,2;
 color:#000000;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:silver;
 border-width:1px;
 border-color:#000000;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #box-table-a td
    {
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:12px;
 padding:2,2,2,2;
 color:#000000;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color:silver;
 border-width:1px;
 text-align:center;
 white-space: nowrap;

    }
    var TableHtml = "<table id='box-table-a'>";
    TableHtml +="<col width=100><col span=3 width=28><col width=100><TR><TH>Field1</TH><TH>Field2</TH><TH>Field3</TH><TH>Field4</TH><TH>Field5</TH></TR>";
    TableHtml +="<TR><TD>" + Field1[0] + "</TD><TD>" + Field2[0] + "</TD><TD>" + Field3[0] + "</TD><TD>" + Field4[0] + "</TD><TD>" + Field5[0] + "</TD></TR>";
    TableHtml +="</Table>";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Karl

Comment: You're using `table-layout: fixed`, so this is expected behaviour.

Comment: `width:844;` should be `width:844px;` and `padding:2,2,2,2;` should be `padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;`. Though that's probably not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Hi thirtydot,Thanks for your response. I left out a pretty vital point that your response reminded me of. My headings are all rotated, using the following in my CSS:
.rotation
{
width: 15px;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)
}
So this means the column widths shouldn't be affected by no wrapping in the headings. Are you saying that putting in "px" should fix this? Because the widths are all working properly, just the wrapping is being ignored. Thanks

Comment: Just put all necessary px's in and no change. Also tried a different style change (tried aligning to the left) and it did not work so the <col> tags are over-riding everything.

Comment: There's a lot going on here. SharePoint, JavaScript, iffy CSS, `filter` and possibly also Quirks Mode. It's too difficult to suggest anything without seeing your actual page or a [reproduction of the problem](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: That's no problem, I appreciate the effort! I have a temporary solution in place at the moment which will have to do. I just do not leave any spaces in the headings. This prevents the text wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `table-layout: fixed` to `table-layout: inherit` if that doesn't work the way you want, maybe you might get lucky with `table-layout: auto`. Also be sure to include px in your dimensions.